# Can I use maven to find but not download the latest version of a dependency?

Tags: maven-2

How can I use maven to determine if there are updates to any of the third party jars that the project uses without actually modifying the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that [`versions:display-dependency-updates`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) is what you're looking for.